# serving static files on a separate server

Tags: django, deployment, django-staticfiles

I'm creating a website with django.  There isn't much static content ( maybe 20 images, and 5-10 css/javascript docs).

I read up on [Managing Static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in django.  Do I need to deploy my static content on a separate server, or will it work fine since I have very little static content?  currently, I'm accessing all my css files and images with the actual path name instead of using "{{STATIC_URL}}".

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use {% static %} to access static files. Please see [Django's official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) on this.

Answering your question: you do not need to keep your static files on a separate server but it is highly recommended. The main reason is performance. They will be served directly from HTTP server avoiding additional load on application server. Also, they will be cached by server/client.

You can find a lot of article on this topic. Also check official docs: [deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 0):

You will at least need an HTTP server running on whatever you're running your django project from, and it's highly recommended that you use a separate server for your static files apart from your app logic.

Secondly, it's very bad practice not to use {{ STATIC_URL }} or a similar item.  Absolute paths are evil.  If the project changes machines, or if it needs multiple versions, etc.  These paths could very well change.

Comment: I can't see why the OP would need a separate server for such a small site. Assuming they're using mod_wsgi for the dynamic part, the same Apache instance is fine for the static part.

Comment: You wouldnt need a separate box but you'd need a web server or config running on the box capable of serving static files, separate from the django setup. AFAIK anyhow, and that's what djangos docs recommend.

Comment: But as I said, if they're using mod_wsgi, they already have that server: Apache. The docs give a perfectly good example of how to serve static and dynamic content from the same instance.

Comment: I guess that would be [this example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-the-site-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server).